# 2-d int array storing information of char

Tags: c++, arrays, string

There are two strings and i need to compare if they are different and if they are different , i need to mark their index.
First string is :"bundle" and second string is "double" ,so i need to do (b,d)=index 0  simlarly (u,o)=1. I got  this piece of code which uses an 2-d int array but how can an int array store such information.Later in the code , there is a loop from  char a to z.So how are they being compared letter,look at the comment in codes?

```
         // for (i='a';i<='z';i++)
          for (j=i+1;j<='z';j++)
         if (x[i][j] && x[j][i])// how x[i][j] is used here with char//
        // main code begins here
        int x[256][256],n,i,j,ans,k;
        string a,b;
        main()
           {
              cin>>n;
              cin>>a>>b;
             for (i=0;i<n;i++)
               {
                  if (a[i] != b[i])
                     {
                      x[a[i]][b[i]]=i+1;// but a[i] and b[j] are characters and x is 2-d int array
                      ans++;
                      }
                }
           for (i='a';i<='z';i++)
           for (j=i+1;j<='z';j++)
            if (x[i][j] && x[j][i])
                {
                 cout<<ans-2<<endl;
                 cout<<x[i][j]<<" "<<x[j][i]<<endl;
                return 0;
                 }
              for (i='a';i<='z';i++)
              for (j='a';j<='z';j++)
              for (k='a';k<='z';k++)
              if (x[i][j] && x[j][k])
                  {
                  cout<<ans-1<<endl;
                  cout<<x[i][j]<<" "<<x[j][k]<<endl;
                  return 0;
                  }
```

Comment: That looks like a lot of code for something you can do with [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch). Even if you can't use `std::mismatch` itself, its implementation should give you an idea of how you can implement finding the position where the strings differ much easier.

Comment: mismatch is not important but how we are storing a[i] and b[j] in 2-d array int while both a[i] and b[i] are char @BartvanNierop

Comment: A `char` is nothing more than some data that is one byte. An `int` is (usually) 4 bytes. Assigning a `char` to an `int` simply sets the `int`'s most significant bytes to `0x00` and its least significant byte to whatever value the `char` had. Note that this is slightly simplified, because it does not take the sign bit into consideration.

Comment: will array X store X(b,d) OR X(98,100)? @BartvanNierop

Comment: `'b' == 98` and `'d'  == 100`. They are the same thing in memory, just represented differently in your text editor and by your output function. Try it: `printf("%c %c", 100, 'd');` So the answer to your question _does it store X('b', 'd') or X(98, 100)_ is _yes, it does_.

Comment: yes it just prints d d for 100 and 'd'